# Bank REST API Integration

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, integration, callout

I'm planning a personal project in Salesforce where I'd like to connect to my bank account and retrieve real-time transaction data as well as historical transactional data. This is to keep track of my spendings and and understand the trend over time.

Specifically, I want transactions I make today to be displayed in a Lightning Web Component (LWC).

I'd like to understand the security challenges involved when connecting to my personal account, especially considering that my bank supports the OAuth 2.0 security protocol and whether it’s advisable to implement it in Salesforce dev org securely. The bank API supports REST HTTPS callout with JSON as a response.

Could you please guide me on how to get started and ensure a secure implementation? I specifically haven’t worked with this scenario before and appreciate your expert opinions.

Comment: I doubt any bank exposes real-time account information APIs for retail usage. Isn't it?

Comment: You will need to read Trailhead modules and other tutorials explaining Flow callouts or Apex callouts.

Comment: @DavidCheng I’m well versed with making callouts using apex or flow. My question is more on the security implications of calling my personal bank account API from Salesforce and whether it’s the right approach. I’m planning to use my dev org but I’m wondering if there’s any alternative approach instead of directly making a callout to API from Salesforce.